# Possible bound on generator in terms of the semigroup it generates?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Suppose $T$ is a $C_0$-semigroup with $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M \geq 0$ such that $$\| T(t) \| \leq M e^{\omega t}.$$ Let $A$ be the generator for $T$ and let $\xi_1, ..., \xi_n >0$ be constants. I want to get some form of a bound of $\| (\xi_1 \cdots \xi_n)^{-1} (\xi_1^{-1} - A)^{-1} \cdots (\xi_n^{-1} - A)^{-1} \|$ in terms of $T$. I've attempted the following. $$\| (\xi_1 \cdots \xi_n)^{-1} (\xi_1^{-1} - A)^{-1} \cdots (\xi_n^{-1} - A)^{-1} \| \leq \frac{1}{\xi_1 \cdots \xi_n} \prod_{i=1}^n \| (\xi_i - A)^{-1} \| \\
 \leq \frac{1}{\xi_1 \cdots \xi_n} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{M}{\text{Re}(\xi_i^{-1}) - \omega}$$ Can I get this to be less than the supremum of $T$?

Comment: Shouldn't $\xi_i$ be greater than $\omega$?

Comment: @Pedro I'm not given that assumption

Comment: Presuming $A$ is the generator of $T(t)$ (rather than itself), it might be helpful to note that $T(t) = e^{At} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(sI-A)^{-1}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ indicates the Laplace transform.

Comment: @SZN What is $s$? $s = \xi_i$?

Comment: Actually my question should be: Shouldn't $\xi_i$ be less than $\omega^{-1}$? If not, why $\|(\xi_i^{-1}-A)^{-1}\|\leq \frac{M}{\xi_i^{-1}-\omega}$?

Comment: The generic Laplace transform argument. You can replace it with $\xi$ or whatever other label you want, so long as it is a complex argument.

Comment: @Pedro I understand the source of confusion, I therefore don't think my estimate is legitimate.

Comment: @SZN I would prefer not to use the Laplace transform, since I can't guarantee any condition on the $\xi$ other than that they are positive.

Comment: @user412674 How do you know that $(\xi_i^{-1}-A)$ is invertible?

Comment: @user412674 In response to your last comment, your estimate is indeed legitimate under suitable assumptions (see my post).

Answer (score 0):

*Not a complete answer, but too long to be posted as a comment.*

1. You have an operator $A$ which is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $T=\{T(t)\}$ satisfying
   $$\|T(t)\|\leq Me^{\omega t}$$
   for $\omega\in\mathbb R$ and $M\geq 0$.
2. You want to get a bound for $\left\|\prod \xi_i^{-1}(\xi_i^{-1}-A)^{-1}\right\|$, where $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ are arbitrary positive constants.

Given only the informations in 1, I can't even see how to ensure that $(\xi_i^{-1}-A)$ is invertible for arbitrary $\xi_i>0$. So, I'm going to consider an extra hypothesis:

> Assume that $\omega\leq 0$.

**Note.** This hypothesis is not totally restrictive. There are important cases in which it is fulfilled, for example, if $T$ is of contractions or exponentially stable (but I have no idea if it is relevant for you).

Under this assumption, the Feller-Miyadera-Phillips Theorem implies that $(0,\infty)\subset \rho (A)$ with
$$\|(\lambda-A)^{-1}\|\leq \frac{M}{\lambda-\omega},\quad\forall \ \lambda>0$$

and thus, as in your calculation, we get the bound

$$\left\|\prod \xi_i^{-1}(\xi_i^{-1}-A)^{-1}\right\|
\leq \prod \xi_i^{-1}\left\| (\xi_i^{-1}-A)^{-1}\right\|
\leq \prod \xi_i^{-1}\frac{M}{\xi_i^{-1}-\omega}
= \prod \frac{M}{1-\xi_i\omega}\leq M^n.
$$

**Remark.** The main point of the above argument is that $\xi_i>0$ (as you want) and $\omega\leq 0$ (as I assumed) imply $\xi_i^{-1}>\omega$ and this makes possible to apply the Feller-Miyadera-Phillips Theorem. So, the above estimate is valid provided that $\xi_1^{-1},...,\xi_n^{-1}>\omega$ (which happens for arbitrary $\xi_1,...,\xi_n>0$ if $T$ is of contraction or exponentially stable, as I already said).

Comment: Thanks, My assumptions are that $T$ is a bounded $C_0$-semigroup of contractions on a Banach space. Shouldn't this imply that $\| T(t) \| \leq 1$? Under these assumptions, we're justified in taking $\omega \leq 0$?

Comment: @u @user412674 Yes, it does. By definition, a semigroup is of contraction if it satisfy that estimate with $M=1$ and $\omega=0$. In this case, you can use Hille-Yosida instead of Feller-Miyadera-Phillips (which generalizes Hille-Yosida and is needed if $w<0$).

Comment: @user412674 You have asked: *Can I get this to be less than the supremum of $T$?* The answer is yes because, as your semigroup is of contractions, the estimate becomes
$$\left\|\prod \xi_i^{-1}(\xi_i^{-1}-A)^{-1}\right\|
\leq \prod \frac{1}{1-\xi_i0}= 1=\sup_{t\geq 0} \|T(t)\|$$

Comment: Is there any way of bounded $\| T(t) \|$ by its generator?

Comment: @user412674 What do you mean by "by its generator"? Have you any specific form of a bound in mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59658/discussion-between-pedro-and-user412674).